# Why is implicit casting is much faster than explicit in JS? Is implicit casting a good practice?

Tags: javascript, performance, type-conversion

I know it is cleaner and nicer to cast types like `String(1234)` and `Number("1234")`, but I just tried to benchmark alternative ways of doing the same thing, specifically `"" + 1234  // -> "1234"` and `- - "1234"  // -> 1234`.

The results were quite surprising (for me). I iterated over each way 100,000,000 times in Chrome.

I used this simple code.

```
var then = Date.now(); 
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
    var a = - - "1234";
}; 
console.log(Date.now() - then);
```

`Number("1234")` took 2351 ms whereas `- - "1234"` took only 748 ms.

Similarly for the other way around, `String(1234)` took 3701 ms whereas `"" + 1234` took only 893 ms.

The difference is surprisingly huge.

My questions are: What makes the explicit casting so much slower than implicit? My intuition tells me it should be the other way around.

Is it a good practice to use implicit casting? Especially the hacky `- - "1234"`? Are there nicer alternatives?

PS: I just tried the same in Firefox. It was about 500 times slower (but still the implicit conversion was much faster). What is going on? Is it connected to branch prediction or something similar? I guess I am benchmarking wrong.

Comment: `- - "1234"` can be written as `+ "1234"`

Comment: These aren't casts, they're instantiations. You haven't shown your benchmarking code but chances are the runtimes are better at handling and optimizing what amount to constant expressions vs instantiations.

Comment: @andlrc If written just like that, it returns number. But if inside an expression like `123 + "123"` it returns `"123123"`. You could write it like `123 + + "123"`, but I feel like it is quite similarly confusing to `123 - - "123"`

Comment: @BoltKey—but you would never literally write that, the expression is more likely to be `1234 - x`, in which case the `-` operator converts *x* to Number anway (as do `*` and `/` also). The only time explicit conversion is required is with the `+` operator, so only ever something like `1234 + +x`.

Comment: Looking at your code, it's seems to be mostly what I suspected. `- - "1234"` is something that can be identified as a constant expression very early on. That's just the number 1234. It's created once. Your other variant actually asks for a zillion Number objects to be instantiated and then thrown away.

Comment: @pvg: There is no instantiation, the `String` and `Number` functions are called without `new`. There are no objects at all.

Comment: @Bergi you're right. The point was one is a trivially and early-optimized constant expression and the other one is not and neither are 'casts'. But should have have been more carefully when pendanticing, myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you instead of using a constant, if you use `i` instant then the result will be a quite different:

```
console.time('a');
for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; ++i) {
    var a = String(i);
}; 
console.timeEnd('a');
console.time('b');
for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; ++i) {
    var a = "" + i;
}; 
console.timeEnd('b');
```

Output:

```
a: 1062.192ms
b: 884.535ms
```

Note I have to remove a power of 10 as well. `100000000 === 1e8` And I uses `1e7`.

This suggests that there is happening a lot of optimization under the hood when working with a constant as in your benchmark.

And now `Number(...)` seems to be faster:

```
console.time('a');
for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; ++i) {
    var a = - - ("" + i);
}; 
console.timeEnd('a');
console.time('b');
for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; ++i) {
    var a = Number("" + i);
}; 
console.timeEnd('b');
```

Output:

```
a: 2010.903ms
b: 1557.735ms
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Firefox being extremely slow is caused by its bad optimization of constant expressions, right?

Comment: @BoltKey I have to admit that I can only guess to why Firefox is so much slower. But as for my test - without constants - Firefox is still ~10 times slower than Chromium. And roughly 15% slower with `i` instead of a constant.

Comment: @andlrc are you testing this in the console, by any chance? That doesn't perform all optimizations in all browsers. I tested all of these in Chrome, Safari and Firefox they run at similar times with Safari being fastest, followed by FF and Chrome. Since this is a highly contrived synthetic microbenchmark it's not really sensible to say that one of the approaches is reliably faster than the other nor are the differences between the browsers particularly significant.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, use of the unary `+` and `-` operators should be faster than calling *Number* and *String* since they use the internal *ToNumber* and *ToString* methods to convert the operands to number Type, whereas *Number* and *String* require the additional overhead of a function call.

However, theory doesn't always match practice as it's likely very simple to optimise `Number(x)` to `+x`, or vice versa, which ever the compiler thinks is faster.

> What makes the explicit casting so much slower than implicit? My intuition tells me it should be the other way around.

As always, the results you get in a particular version of a browser don't necessarily apply to other browsers or even other versions of the same browser. In theory, explicit conversion should be slower, but I wouldn't depend on that across implementations.

> Is it a good practice to use implicit casting? Especially the hacky - - "1234"? Are there nicer alternatives?

That should be `-'1234'` and I would say "no" since the `-` operator converts it's argument to Number anyway, there is never a need to write `x - -y`.

It's much more common to use unary `+` for conversion in conjunction with the addition operator `+`, and in most circumstances it's equally clear to write `+x` or `Number(x)`. So use:

```
x + +y
```

and save some typing.